# Automatically scheduling CRON jobs via API

Tags: python, api, cron

So, I'm working on a specific solution that requires the creation of jobs that should run at a specific time, and complete a certain action.

We've built a GUI where the client inputs params required for that action, and the time when that job should be started. When that happens, there should be an action in the background that creates that cron-job with the above-mentioned params and starts at the specified time.

The code for those jobs would all be the same, just the input params and the time would change.

I'm not aware of a service or an already built solution that would help me in these cases, so that is why I ask for guidance.

Comment: Many distros have tools for managing cron that are integrated with their package manager. But it sounds like "at" (good luck googling that) https://linux.die.net/man/1/at is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to create cron jobs (i.e. jobs that are executed at regular intervals until they are removed/disabled again) or just single actions that should run at a specified time?

If the latter (your description somewhat sounds like it) and your server is running reliably, you could just fork off a command that waits until the desired time, then executes the job.

Alternatively, you could keep a list of scheduled jobs in a database table and retrieve and execute jobs whose execution time has been reached by a simple script run by cron. Unless the execution time is critical, this would probably be the easiest solution.

Or, as @user10489 noted, use the `at` command if your server runs on a POSIX compatible operating system.

Comment: It's more of a single action run at a specified time, than a cron job.

Comment: `at` might be more appropriate than cron for this if you want to use an existing service.